# Cannot load native library into Android project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

When I try to load native library into Android project I receive exception with following message:

`Cannot load library: reloc_library[1286]:  1830 cannot locate '__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'...`

Library was built for Android, with using 4.6 toolchain.

What might be the reason of it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of the NDK?  r8e is current.

Comment: @fadden It was built using NDK version r8c, but I can reproduce this issue with r8d also.